# Can I use IORef as a kind of "mutex" in this way?

Tags: haskell

I have an operation that must be executed in the mutual exclusive way. In other languages I can do something like (Python like pseudocode):

```
with myLock:
  # here lock is acquired
  do mutual exclusive operation
# here lock is released
```

Sure, I can do it in Haskell with `MVar`: to take it and then to put it back. But I want to do it with `IORef` as:

```hs
-- somewhere
duringOperation :: IORef Bool

.....

-- operation execution:

    mayIStart <- atomicModifyIORef' duringOperation $ \case
      -- tuple is treated as (lock/keep-locked, may I start the operation)
      True  -> (True, False)
      False -> (True, True)
    if mayIStart then do
      -- here I am doing my operation in a mutual exclusive way
      ...
      -- after completion I reset duringOperation flag
      atomicWriteIORef' _duringOperation False
    else
      -- something else...
```

It looks like typical "atomic" or "synchronized" flag in other languages. But I am not sure how it's safe in Haskell and with an usage of `IORef` for such goal. Again, my idea is to do it with `IORef`. Is it really safe (the operation will be really mutual exclusive)?

Comment: Why do you want to invent a weird tool to do this instead of using the standard tool designed to do exactly this?

Comment: @amalloy Reasons are: 1) TBH I don't think that `IORef` is "weird" for this coz it's standard solution in most languages ("guarded" flag) and `MVar` IMHO is more weird: it allows multiple producers which looks very weird, 2) theoretical interest - I want to understand is it really safe? 3) `IORef` is more lightweight solution and sometimes it maybe even faster. 2nd is the most important reason sure :)

Comment: It looks safe to me, but it does not allow a thread to wait (except for busy waiting). I wonder how common that use case is. Even C++ has `std::mutex` which provides a waiting `lock()`.

Comment: Mutexes are indeed a standard primitive, but they are a low level primitive that [doesn't scale well or safely](https://www.scaler.com/topics/operating-system/mutex-in-os/). That is why Haskell went to the trouble of providing higher-level mechanisms that don't suffer from those disadvantages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's safe. That is precisely what the `atomic` in `atomicModifyIORef` means. From the Fine Documentation:

> Atomically modifies the contents of an IORef.
>
> This function is useful for using IORef in a safe way in a multithreaded program. If you only have one IORef, then using atomicModifyIORef to access and modify it will prevent race conditions.

I believe you do not need to write atomically when releasing the "mutex", i.e. `writeIORef duringOperation False` should be fine -- believing that the operation is running when it isn't is safe, just less efficient.